# Last decimal digit of any perfect square must be $0,1,4,5,6$ or $9$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Last decimal digit of any perfect square must be $0,1,4,5,6$ or $9$

My Proof:
Ten cases exist, yielding the following equalities:

$$(1\mod{10})^2 = 1\mod{10}$$
$$(2\mod{10})^2 = 4\mod{10}$$
$$(3\mod{10})^2 = 9\mod{10}$$
$$(4\mod{10})^2 = 6\mod{10}$$
$$(5\mod{10})^2 = 5\mod{10}$$
$$(6\mod{10})^2 = 6\mod{10}$$
$$(7\mod{10})^2 = 9\mod{10}$$
$$(8\mod{10})^2 = 4\mod{10}$$
$$(9\mod{10})^2 = 1\mod{10}$$
$$(0\mod{10})^2 = 0\mod{10}$$

Since the proposition holds for all possible cases, the proposition holds.

Is this an acceptable proof for the proposition?

What is the simplest proof for this?

Note: This is not a homework question, just a question from a weekly tutorial sheet.

Comment: This is exhaustive, so it works.

Comment: @wckronholm I feel as though I should try to avoid using exhaustive proofs, they seem really inefficient.

Comment: No problem if it is homework-you have shown your work as requested by the FAQ and asked a good related question.  +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fine proof.  You could consider a few less cases in two similar ways.  You could do it mod $2$ and $5$, then combine the results with the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  You could do $0, \pm 1, \pm2, \pm 3, \pm 4, 5$  Both would show off more math knowledge than this approach, but I am not sure either would be less work.  For moduli higher than $10$, the investment might be repaid.

Comment: It appears a similar proof can be completed for $(x \mod 10)^3,0 \leq x \leq 9 $, can a similar proof be completed for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+,(x \mod 10)^n, 0 \leq x \leq 9$

Comment: Yes, you can do this for any modulus.  As the modulus gets higher, the work grows.  You probably want those $\ge$ signs to be $\le$ signs.  For the cubes, every digit can end a cube.  For any even power, there are no more than six ending digits, because $(-1)^2=1,$, so $1$ and $9$ always end in the same, as do $2$ and $8$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For a more "clever" solution (but yours looks perfect):

As $10=5\times 2$, let us consider 
$$
x^2 = 10a + 5b+ r
\\ 0\le 5b+r< 10
\\ 0\le r< 5
$$
then reducing modulo 5:
$$
r = x^2 \in \{ 0,1,4
\}\mod 5\\
5b+r \in \{ 0,1,4,0+5=5,1+5=6,4+5=9
\}\mod 5\\
$$